# Power BI, Power Query - Go trough list and add text with each step (for each)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a list for example:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Now I want to create a query in power query that will create a text like this:

"The letters are: "  A B C D

I already have this query:

```
let
    xx=   KEYListfunction(),
    list = Text.Split(xx, ","),
    text = "",
   loop = List.Accumulate(list, 0, (state, current) => text = text &  " " & current ))
in
loop
```

But the result only says "FALSE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
let
    list = {"A".."D"},
    text = "The letters are: " & Text.Combine(list, ", ")
in
    text
```